# Problems querying Factual API data using Ruby wrapper

Tags: ruby, json, api

Trying to implement Factual API with provided Ruby wrapper.  Looking to return all Bars within certain number of meters of a geo point.  My query looks like this:

```
factual.table("places").search("category_id"=>"312").geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [40.7811, -73.98], "$meters" => 10000}).rows
```

This returns a 200:OK response, but 0 records (even though that location is in Manhattan).  I'm pretty sure there's a problem with the way I'm passing in the category info.

Per the API documentation, I've also tried passing the category data like this, which returns a syntax error:

```
factual.table("places").filters("category_ids" => {"category_ids":["6"]}).geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [40.7811, -73.98], "$meters" => 10000}).rows
```

and this, which returns the Factual error *references unknown field category_ids*:

```
factual.table("places").filters("category_ids" => {"$in" => ["312", "338"]}).geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [40.7811, -73.98], "$meters" => 10000}).rows
```

I'm following the documentation samples here and using v3: https://github.com/Factual/factual-ruby-driver/wiki/Read-API and here: http://developer.factual.com/display/docs/Places+API+-+Global+Place+Attributes

EDIT:

I've also tried changing the `filters` method to `search` like this:

```
  factual.table("places").search("category_ids" => {"$in" => ["312", "338"]}).geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [40.7811, -73.98], "$meters" => 10000}).rows
```

This returns records with 338 in the address, irrespective of category. Very strange.  I've been trying different things for hours. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with how I'm passing in category information.  I'm following the docs as closely as I can, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you try running example queries in your console? the problem could be with your keys

Comment: Yes. The keys are fine.  I was able to get data returned from the api before I tried to limit by category.  Also, running in debug mode, so I can see the request being generated to the API.

Comment: increase the radius and check you are doing something wrong and I cant help you like this

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I've edited my question several times to show what I've tried and what hasn't worked.  I did increase the radius and removed it altogether. If you need me to post more console output or something, just let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: No the problem is not with your question. I had used Factual long time ago and have no code currently to test this and help you. but you are definitely doing something silly there that is causing this error. Try with different combinations. I.ie without the location part or without the category part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
factual.table("places").filters("category" => "Bars")
  .geo("$circle" => {"$center" =>[40.7811, -73.98] , "$meters" => 1000}).rows
```

Comment: Thanks @dfd. I actually had to change the table name to "places-v3" in order for the category_ids to work like this: `factual.table("places-v3").filters("category_ids" => {"$in" => ["312"]}).geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [40.7811, -73.98], "$meters" => 10000}).rows`